# Unable to bing blob image when using Primeng avatar

Tags: angular, primeng

In official doc images are selected from assets directory

```
        <div class="card">
            <h5>Image - Badge</h5>
                <p-avatar image="assets/showcase/images/demo/organization/walter.jpg" pBadge value="4" severity="danger" styleClass="mr-2" size="xlarge"></p-avatar>
        </div>
```

I would get image from my component ( blob image ) .

```
    let imageBlog = await (response as any).blob().catch(this.unhandledFetchError); // Get image data as raw binary data

    this.photo= URL.createObjectURL(imageBlog)
```

`<p-avatar [image]='photo'></p-avatar>`

It's not working

When I open the image in browser I get it.

Comment: It should work if you use a normal image with src. But maybe PrimeNG doesn't support it. I would recommend just converting the blob to base64 string and provide that as image to the p-avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it needs to be sanitilized

```
this.photo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(imageBlog))
```

Inject sanitizer

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```